# Recursively adding node to end of linkedlist

Tags: java, recursion, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am trying to recursively append an element to the end of a Linked List .However, Nothing seems to be added. I use a private helper method so I can use the reference as a parameter. I don't run into any exceptions, however, my test cases show that nothing at all has been added to the list! I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and have no idea where to start. Your help is very appreciated.

```
public void addLast(E element) {
    addLast(element,first);
}

private void addLast(E element, Node ref) {
    if (ref == null) {
        ref = new Node(element);
        n++;
            } else if (ref.next == null) {
                    ref.next = new Node(element);
                    n++;
    } else {
        addLast(element, ref.next);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, what is n? Is your problem that the list is always empty? If yes, then try changing 'ref = new Node(element)' under the first if block to first = new Node(element), where 'first' is your list's head pointer.

Comment: Could you please post an example that results in an empty LinkedList?

Answer (score 6):

You have to do something like this.
Refer [this link](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-21/lectures/llrecursion/lecture.html)  for explanation.

```
private Node addLast(E element, Node ref) {
    if (ref == null) {
        ref = new Node(element);

    } else {
        ref.next = addLast(element, ref.next);
    }
    return ref;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void addLast(Node node){

   while(root.next != null){
            root = root.next;

            if (root.next == null){
                root.next = node;
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Not recursive because you don't need it...